# wxPython TypeError: String or Unicode type required error

Tags: python, twitter

I am making a twitter python client with wxPython, but only one thing isn't working. Please help. This is that part of the code:

```
getstatus = twitter.Api()
    pullstatus=wx.TextEntryDialog(panel, "Type which users to pull a status from.", 'Twitter Post Reader', 'Person')
    if pullstatus.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
        puller=pullstatus.GetValue()

    get = getstatus.GetUserTimeline(puller)
    wx.StaticText(panel, -1, get, (200,450))
```

It's only on the last line, when I type the variable `get`, that it throws an error.
EDIT: I fixed the code. Here is what I did:

```
getstatus = twitter.Api()
    pullstatus=wx.TextEntryDialog(panel, "Type which users to pull a status from.", 'Twitter Post Reader', 'Person')
    if pullstatus.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
        puller=pullstatus.GetValue()

    statusArray = getstatus.GetUserTimeline(puller)
    str_list = []
    for s in statusArray:
        str_list.append(s.text)
    wx.StaticsText(panel, -1, ''.join(str_list), (10,300))
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`GetUserTimeline()` returns a list of status messages, not a string.  You need to convert the desired post to a string in order to show it.